# How to customize highchart

Tags: highcharts

I want to make some customization to Highcharts. I want to make the high chart look like the image, please have a look at the image:

[image: Desired look]

How can I achieve this through Highcharts?

Comment: What have you got so far? Show us some code you've tried.

Comment: the code that i have used is here jsfiddle.net/PS8WJ/ and it is working now but i cannot remove the line of the x-axis beside CC or WCDL please help. I also want to control the size of each of the stack bar. Please help thanks.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly : Thanks your jsfiddle helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there with your jsfiddle. Try adding this:

```
xAxis: {
  lineWidth:0,
  tickLength:0,
```

To alter the bar width, use a combination of pointWidth and pointPadding

```
plotOptions:{
    bar:{
        pointWidth:10,
        pointPadding:10
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. can you please do me another favor, i just want to set the width of each stack bar can you just tell me how to do that like the stack in this picture - [link](http://twitpic.com/cgl0o2)

Comment: Updated answer for piointwidth and pointPadding. Try different values to get the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HAB7t/

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
}
```

For more help you can have a look at the Highcharts API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Answer (score 0):

You should use bar chart with enabled datalabels.http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic 
Gaps between each bar, you can define by groupPadding / pointPadding / pointWidth. All of them are available documented in docs. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts